# Ubuntu 22.04 on MSI laptop webcam no longer working

Tags: uefi, webcam, msi

I have a MSI MS-1551 A10M laptop with Ubuntu 22.04. I have had the internal webcam working before with Zoom / Cheese but now even after an upgrade to 22.04 Cheese says Device not found.

I have done a UEFI upgrade as well but to no avail.

There is nothing listed in `/dev/video` either. There are no /dev/video* folers.

I have tried the MSI Fn+F6 for toggling the webcam as well which used to work prior to an upgrade I did to Ubuntu. I hoped upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 and upgrading the BIOS would resolve it.

Any further suggestions would be great ! Thanks

[dmesg & lsucb & lspci commands output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvfhS.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text.

Answer (score 3):

Check for Camera, it could be locked. Unlock it by pressing Fn+F6 on your keyboard.

It happened with me too on my MSI laptop.